# Escape <script> tag in PHP search function breaks CSS of website

Tags: php, xss, html-escape-characters

I have the following input on my search.php:

```
<input type="text" id="inputboxSearch" name="q" value="<?php if(isset($_GET["q"])){echo htmlspecialchars($_GET["q"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');} ?>"
```

and the following code on results.php page:

```
<input type="text" id="inputboxSearch" name="q" value="<?php if(isset($_GET["q"])){echo htmlspecialchars($_GET["q"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');} ?>"
$query = isset($_GET['q']) ? filter_var($_GET["q"], FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS) : '';
$query = strip_tags($query);
$query = trim($query);
<?php if ($query != '') {echo "You searched for '" . htmlspecialchars($query) . "' ";}?>
```

The script runs fine with every search term but the CSS of the website breaks if the search starts with the term < script (without space)

What is the proper and secure way to search for < script > ?

Comment: please do you want to search with or escape the ```script tags``` ?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with this code. It should properly escape any `<` and `>` characters which would otherwise affect the HTML on the page. Perhaps something else on the page is causing the problem?

Comment: I migrated the page from bootstrap to tailwindcss. This was not an issue with bootstrap, maybe there's something else, thanks, I'll check the page again.

Comment: I did some research with chrome inspector and it seems like it was a problem with the tailwind css framework. I was using <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> to include the css when the problem was present. After I swiched to https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/1.4.6/tailwind.min.css the problem disappeared.